# From Spring Roo, is it possible to create an html select with values changing dynamically depending on another 'select' choice?

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo to set up my project. I have one form with two selects, where the values of one are dependent on the value selected on another. Can I create this relationship and the set of values from Roo at all or should I do it manually in my IDE/ text editor instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this requirement to specialized for ROO, therefore you need to implement this part of the application by you own.